# $ \sum_{t=0}^{N}\left ( \frac{B(t) -C(t)}{(1+Z)^t} \right )=0 $, Solve for $Z$

Tags: summation, exponentiation, fractions

Given,

$$
 \sum_{t=0}^{N}\left ( \frac{B(t) -C(t)}{(1+Z)^t} \right )=0
$$

Find $Z$.

This equation is from a book called "Science Under Scarcity: Principles and Practice for Agricultural Research Evaluation and Priority Setting" written by Julian M. Alston; George W. Norton; Philip G. Pardey

The sum is Net Present Value (NPV) is the difference between the present value of cash inflows and the present value of cash outflows over a period of time.

- $t$ represents the time so interval $0..N$ is the time period (in years) in which we calculate the economic effects. 0 is the start year.
- $B(t)$ and $C(t)$ represents the benefits and costs. The values are known for each year $t$
- $Z$ - Internal Rate of Return (IRR) is a metric used in capital budgeting to estimate the profitability of potential investments. The internal rate of return is a discount rate that makes the net present value (NPV) of all cash flows from a particular project equal to zero.

Usually, $Z$ is a known variable and given all the other known values I can calculate the sum for any $t$ in interval $0..N$

What I want to know is what is the value of $Z$ for which the sum (NPV) is 0.

My background is in software engineering. And math is an important component in my background but I'm stuck on solving this equation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I just edited the post and added the Latex formula. Thank you!

Comment: What is $B(t)$ and $C(t)$?

Comment: B and C are functions and their value is known for every $t$

Comment: Can you please show what are those functions?

Comment: @NashJ. I think how those functions look is irrelevant. Z should be a formula and $B(t)$ and $C(t)$ should be in the formula.

Comment: $B(t)$ and $C(t)$ return a known float number for every $t$

Comment: @NashJ. I wrote the formula slightly different: 
$ \sum_{t=0}^{N}\left ( \frac{B_{t} -C_{t}}{(1+Z)^t} \right )=0$ 
Does it make more sense like this?

Comment: You must give more informations about $B(t)$ and $C(t)$. It is impossible to find a simple closed form solution for arbitrary functions $B(t)$ and $C(t)$. If they are polynomials in $t$ then there are closed form solutions.

Comment: guys, I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 1):

$Z$ - Internal Rate Of Return cannot be calculated analytically. I checked different software implementations and "guess-and-check"/"trial-and-error" method is the common way to find it.